# Active Directory 2003 Native mode vs Mixed Mode

Tags: active-directory

My company is switching the Active Directory schema from Mixed Mode to Native Mode. 
Did anyone had any problems when doing this?. It is a one way process and I'm wondering if there are any impacts on the way apps will work with AD. (VB6 or .NET apps)

To give you an example of something that I think is under question mark: there is one old app that resolves users from AD using a linked server in SQL. Would this still work?

Appreciated,
Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason to have problems is if you have any old NT4 domain controllers.  If they're all gone, going native is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of any problems switching form mixed to native, especially not linked servers in SQL. That said, you need to test, test and then test some more...

Here's a quick rundown on the different AD modes:
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5140371.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple switch and has nothing to do with your applications.  Don't forget there is both a domain mode and a forest mode.

Read up here on the differences and what "advantages" come from W2k3 native modes:http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/w2k3/w2k3_mixedvnative.htm

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it would be an issue is if you still had NT4 BDCs in place. If you don't have any NT4 BDCs, then switching to Native Mode will not affect your SQL Servers. Now, with that said, some folks expect to be able to use [user principal name (UPN) format](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327520) (user@domain), but SQL Server doesn't support that. It only supports the standard NetBIOS way of specifying the user (Domain\User). This is true through SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a multi-domain forest, ensure you have strict replication consistency enabled across all your DCs. The FFL upgrade can bring lingering objects out of the woodwork.

Thanks,

Brian Desmond

Active Directory MVP